# How do you create a EC2 Bundle through AWS Management Console?

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-s3

I have a running instance.... I've clicked on the "Instance Actions"

and selected bundle

It asks for a s3 bucket name   - I've entered a bucket name I've created on S3.  However when I click "bundle" it comes up with :-

a little "warning sign" and says "Existing S3 buckets may contain lower case alphanumeric characters, dots, dashes, and possibly underscores (no longer allowed for new buckets)."

kind of implying it can't find the bucket?

Not sure if you have to set anything special on the bucket? or?

either way, I can't get past that point!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

buckets must be ALL lowercase letters.  Sadly the error message is very ambiguous.  The word "may"  should be replaced by "must only"

Answer (score 0):

Did you choose a name with special characters in it?  New bucket names must be all alphanumeric.  So that is really telling you that you used an invalid name.